Asymptotic upper bound on independence number in random graph
currently I'm learning about random graphs, and struggle with the following result, which is supposed to be well known. Nonetheless I couldn't find a proof of this, and I'm stuck proving it myself:
Let $n$ be an integer and $0\le d \le n$.
Consider a random $n$-vertex
graph $G$ formed by including each edge independently with probability $d/n$.
If $d = \omega (1)$, then with probability $1 - o(1)$, we have
$\alpha(G) \le  (1 + o(1)) \frac{2n \ln d}{d} =: b$.
My approach, which is rather naive, was to introduce a random variable $X$, which counts the number of independent sets of size $b+1$ in $G$.
Then I used Markovs inequality to upper bound the probability of $X>0$:
$P[X>0]\le E[X] = \sum_{J\subseteq V(G), |J|=b+1}(1-d/n)^{b+1\choose 2 } = \binom{n}{b+1}  (1-d/n)^{b+1\choose 2 }$
The last inequality uses the linearity of expectation and the fact that a $b+1$-vertex set is independent with probability $(1-d/n)^{b+1\choose 2 }$, because all possible edges are not included.
Now I tried to show that the last expression is $o(1)$, and I threw various inequalities on it, trying to simplify the expression and then taking the limit of $n$ to infinity. But I didn't manage to get it.
Am I on the right track here? Or is there a different approach, which is better? Any help is appreciated.
PS: I also tried simple cases like $d=n$ or $d= n/2$ and they work, which leads me to believe that this approach might also do the trick.

to make your life easier, just use $b$ instead of $b+1$. Use the inequality
$\binom nb \le (ne/b)^b$ and $(1-d/n) \sim e^{-d/n}$. Then take your new expression and write it all as $e^{blah}$. The blah just needs to tend to $-\infty$

@dbal Thank you, I will try this!
